# label click event not working with Check box jquery in some android OS

Tags: android, jquery, css, cordova, mobile-webkit

Here is a Html page where i am using jquery and css with phonegap and implementing the UI , However this code is correctly working on webkit of Andorid OS 4.x version while the check while the function is not getting called in Label named **changePageTermUse()** in Android 2.3 device , i e clicking on label text refresh the checkbox only , while the same logic works on android 4.x devices , Whether I am doing something wrong or do i need to implement other way for android old version of OS like 2.3 .. etc

For Reference I am attaching the image at the end

```
<div class="chkbox-large-text">
    <label>
        <input name="checkbox-0 " type="checkbox" data-iconpos="left" id="Chkterms" />
        I accept the <a style="text-decoration:underline;" onclick="changePageTermUse()">Terms of Use</a>.
    </label>
</div>
```

JS

```
function changePageTermUse() {
    $.mobile.changePage( "#terms-of-service", {transition: "none"});
}
```

**Term of Use** label text has click event that is working in Android 4.x but not working in 2.3 OS Any suggestion will be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

give the same values of label for and id of checkbox

```
 <label for="aa">
 <input type="checkbox" id="aa">
```

Comment: Clicking in the rectangle(see image)  area the event goes to check box in Andorid 2.3 based device and ur this also does not  seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I had a Problem with no response on a click Event on Android. But it worked on iOS. I found out, that the Parent div had no height. Always check this...